# filterAcceptsColumn in QSortFilterProxyModel returns logical or visible column index

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I wanted to know what source_column is ins filterAcceptsColumn . Is that a logical or visible index ?

Comment: It can't be visible index because models know nothing about visual representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the index from the source model, thus "logical'. Visible indexes are an a property of item views and thus unknown to any model (both source and proxy model).